# Export DNN 4.0 database data into dnn07.02

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a site developed in dnn 4.0. I want to export all data of this site into Fresh Installed site (dnn 7.0.2). How  we can do it .. Please give an idea or any tool , module.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a tool that will do this for you. You have two options as I see it.

1) Upgrade the 4.0 site to 7.0 (this would be my recommended option) You would only do this after doing a full backup of the site and database, and you should do it in a test environment first.
2) Manually migrate all of the pages and content from the 4.0 site to a new 7.0 site.